# Multithreads - passing arguments and receiving results

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying various options on working with threads. I wrote the code below, but it does not work as expected. How can I fix the code, so that the main function will correctly display the product?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreads
{
    class Program
    {
        static int prod;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Multiply(2, 3));
            thread.Start();         
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // do some other work until thread completes
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod); // I expect 6 and it shows 0
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            prod = a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect 6? You wait for 1 second after you start the thread, but the thread will take 2 seconds to complete. So prod will still be 0.

Comment: Klaus, your answer does not help me in solving the problem. I already know the prod is still 0 and I still don't know how to fix it. The amount of time the thread takes should be irrelevant.

Comment: To solve the problem, use Alchemy's answer. I just wanted to help you **understanding** what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you should be using non-blocking tasks, volatile properties and other coroutine principals, the immediate reason your program does not work as intended is because you didn't re-join the child thread back into the parent. See [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332368(v=vs.71).aspx)

Without the join, the Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod); occurs before the assignment prod = a * b;

```
static int prod;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => Multiply(2, 3));
    thread.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { // do some other work until thread completes
        Console.Write(i + " ");
       Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    thread.Join(); // Halt current thread until the other one finishes.
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod); // I expect 6 and it shows 0
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static void Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    prod = a * b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alchemy, it worked after adding thread.Join(). I was hoping to call the Multiply function in a non-blocking way. I also just tried to write a simple program using tasks from a tutorial, but it does not compile. I will post some more badly written code involving tasks. I am good at writing bad code :)

Comment: @Nick_F Your goal is impossible to reach, you can't both be non blocking AND have the value be computed at this step, the join blocks untill the multiplication is done in this case, so you either block and get the right result, or don't block and get the uninitialized result, you can't have it both ways. Of course if you remove the sleep it might not block because the thread may already be done at the time you get on that line.

Comment: The function Multiply is just a dummy function. In real world, I download and process some data from the internet, and it may take some unknown amount of time until it completes. I am trying to keep my WinForms application responsive while the program is running the function.

Comment: @Nick_F: To keep GUI application responsive during download, use [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) instead of threads. Although it may take some time to wrap your head around it, then it actually makes programming easier then with threads. And `async` is also more suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Nuf, I tried a sample using async and it works pretty well and it is easy to implement and it is also available in .Net 4.5